# sshd - prevent any message shown upon failed login

Tags: ssh, sshd, openssh

I've configured an sshd server to use keys only for login however upon failed login the client displays:

> Permission denied (publickey)

This of course is expected however I want to stop **any** message being returned to the client upon failed login i.e. fail silently.

Is there anyway to configure OpenSSHD to do this?

Comment: This error message was generated by the client.

Comment: OK. Fair point, I didn't think about what is actually happening but then surely the server is returning some sort of message to indicate the reson why the authentication has failed? If so.. can I prevent this..again just fail silently.

Comment: And whoever cast the down-vote please be brave enough to comment here why you have done that instead of providing an explanation or helping me clear up my misunderstanding. I think the whole point of these forums is to ask questions to clear up any misunderstanding, not for those that 'think' they know better to dismiss them by down-voting the question.

Comment: Use the source, Luke!

Comment: Why would you do that? What should server return instead of failure?